# How to re-format the patch after merge in Git?

Tags: git, merge, format-patch

Let's assume that there are two branches, `master` and `slave`, and they edit the same file and the same line. Initially, the contents of the file is

```
foo bar
```

then in the branch `slave` it is edited to become

```
foo bar baz
```

Now the user of branch `slave` formats the patch (`git format-patch master`) and sends it to the user of the branch `master`. In the same time, in the branch `master` the same file is edited and becomes

```
foo bar spam eggs
```

The patch cannot be applied, and `master` asks `slave` to merge and make a new patch. When `master` is merged into `slave` and the conflict is resolved, it's time to reformat the patch. The commit graph looks like this:

```
slave:               master:

foo bar baz spam eggs
    |             \
    |              \
    |                foo bar spam eggs
    |                    |
foo bar baz              |
       \                 |
        \                |
         +---------  foo bar
```

The latest commit (merge) on `slave` looks like:

```
@@@ -1,1 -1,1 +1,1 @@@
- foo bar baz
 -foo bar spam eggs
++foo bar baz spam eggs
```

However, if we now run `git format-patch master`, we still get exactly the same patch as before, which doesn't take merge and conflict resolution into account:

```
@@ -1 +1 @@
-foo bar
+foo bar baz
```

How do you format a patch which would apply against the latest master? I'd like to do it without `rebase`.

Update: `git format rev1..rev2`, where `rev1` and `rev2` are heads of the `master` and `custom` branches respectively, doesn't include changes related to conflict resolution. `git-diff` formats a valid patch, but omits commit messages.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using patches? You should be pushing and pulling between repos.

A merge is not something you can make a patch from. It will follow the first parent only. You can get what you want by using `git diff` and formatting for patch while specifying the 2 different commits to differentiate between.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I use patches, because this is what the upstream wants, and I am not in the control of workflow. I have to format patches which take conflict resolution into account, because I also publish my repo and cannot rebase. `git diff`, unfortunately, doesn't include commit messages.

Comment: There's a way to make a merge have just one parent. A patch from that will get you the outcome you need.

Comment: A merge with just one parent?  How is it possible? Isn't `git-merge` supposed to "join _two_ or more development histories together"?

Comment: You can try --squash which will create a single commit of the merge, but then you lose the ability to traverse the merge back into the original branch.